# AngularJS - Generate HTML on the fly based on a directive

Tags: angularjs

Say I want to generate some Html on the fly but based on the same definition in my directive, how would I achieve this?

My directive is currently expecting JSON:

```
app.directive('myDirective', [function () {
    return {
        template: '<div>A far more impressive template lives here...</div>',
        restrict: 'AE',
        scope: {
            eventData: '='
        },
        link: function ($scope, $element, $attrs) {
            //some cool functions...
        }
    };
}]);
```

Within my ng-repeat element, I have this kinda thing, where the event-data contains the named scope item from the ng-repeat, clause.

```
<div ng-repeat="event in myCtrl.events">
    <my-directive event-data="event"></my-directive>
</div>
```

So how do I go about manually passing in some JSON to use as the data attribute so I can then generate fragments elsewhere, e.g. outside a scoped ng-repeat?

What I am hoping to do is add a function to a controller of mine which just returns a new instance of my directive and then I can plant that somewhere else (I am actually hoping to use as the content of a Google Maps info window).

I hope I have made some sort of sense here!

Thanks

Comment: You should be able to access `eventData` in your Template just like this, since it's on the directives isolated scope: `template: '<div>A far more impressive template lives here: {{eventData}}.</div>'`

Comment: Wat do you mean by `manually pass in JSON`? If you plan on putting this in an info window you would need to use `$compile` within google map API for info window unless you are using a google map directive that already has this feature available

Comment: @charlietfl - That's exactly what I am looking to do. My app is made up of a scroll-able list of locations and then a bunch of markers on a Google Map. When selecting an item from my list, the map zooms to that location, centered on the associated marker, and then I want to show the infoWindow containing the same content as what my directive is currently generating in my list.

Comment: I would just pass the html to map infoWindow  api when event occurs. I have good luck also using angular-ui-map. Will likely be easier using it if you aren't strong with using things like `$compile`